# Problem with semi acoustic guitar sound

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, semi-acoustic-guitar

How can I get rid of the extra resonating sound coming off the amp ?I have been told that it's sympathetic vibrations.I adding a link for the sample.You can hear this weird sound in the background .You have to use headphones.

https://vocaroo.com/i/s14uqeUS2WhP

Comment: new link -https://instaud.io/3F9B

Comment: Used cans - can't hear anything untoward.

Comment: How do you know it's off the amp and not the walls? Small room? Large room? 
Does the amp have an open back? Put the mic inside that box, tape a piece of cardboard on it and see if the additional vibrations are gone (it won't sound good but you'd be eliminating the walls.)

Answer (score 1):

The link did not work.  It is hard to tell which resonances you are referring to.  For an acoustic guitar you want these resonances to create a full sound.  If you have a hollow body electric, or semi-hollow, like a Gibson 335 or other jazz style archtop, and you are using it with an amp then you have to experiment with the effects set up.  This is a notorious problem with hollow body electrics.  The body resonances get amplified and create feedback.  This get worse with distortion and other effects.  It depends on the type of musics you are playing.  But the problem usually isn't bad when you play clean.  Perhaps someone else in this group knows better how to dampen the feedback with effects.

Comment: new link-https://instaud.io/3F9B

Answer (score 0):

On second listen I think I know what you’re asking about. I would try moving the amp farther from the guitar, changing the angle of the guitar or amp or both, turning down the amp, using a larger room, or just not using an amp at all.

You could also get an EQ pedal or use any EQ built into the guitar or amp to try to eliminate the sound.

Most likely a combination of more than one of these ideas will help the most.